# Returning a JSON object from PHP to ajax not working on IOS

Tags: php, jquery, ios, json, ajax

I'm returning a JSON object from PHP to ajax. This works fine on all devices except for iPhone IOS. For some reason on IOS (chrome and safari) instead of the object being passed back to ajax, the JSON object is displayed instead of my webpage.. (on a blank white screen)

```
{"key":"value", etc }
```

PHP:

```
die(json_encode($out));
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    url:         $form.attr( 'action' ),
    type:        $form.attr( 'method' ),
    data:        ajaxData,
    dataType:    'json',
    cache:       false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success:     function( data ) {
                    // something
                 }
});
```

UPDATE:

Sorry people, I didn't give you all the pieces of the puzzle. Looks like the following code was breaking my JS on IOS:

```
$("input[type=radio").change(function() {        
    $($errorMsg).removeClass('error');
    $($errorMsg).hide();
});
```

IOS may not support `input[type=radio]` so i just made a class instead :|

Comment: have you tried removing this? contentType:    false,

Comment: thanks anyway but that didn't fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replying on a real answer:

You forgot the closing bracket on your jQuery selector.

It should be:

`$("input[type=radio]").change(function() {
      $($errorMsg).removeClass('error');
      $($errorMsg).hide();
  });`

Thank me later :)